# Which files have some content in R

Tags: r, grepl

I have a list which contain lines of files, sample of which is shown.

```
list(c("\"ID\",\"SIGNALINTENSITY\",\"SNR\"", "\"NM_012429\",\"7.19739265676517\",\"0.738130599770152\"", 
"\"NM_003980\",\"12.4036181424743\",\"13.753593768862\"", "\"AY044449\",\"8.74973537284918\",\"1.77200602833912\"", 
"\"NM_005015\",\"11.3735054810744\",\"6.76079815107347\""), c("\"ID\",\"SIGNALINTENSITY\",\"SNR\"", 
"\"NM_012429\",\"7.07699512126353\",\"0.987579612646805\"", "\"NM_003980\",\"11.3172936656653\",\"8.38227473088534\"", 
"\"AY044449\",\"9.2865464417786\",\"2.61149606120517\"", "\"NM_005015\",\"10.1228142794354\",\"3.98707517627092\""
), c("ID,SIGNALINTENSITY,SNR", "1,NM_012429,6.44764696592035,0.84120306786724", 
"2,NM_003980,9.52604513443066,3.02404186191898", "3,AY044449,9.11930818670925,2.24361163736047", 
"4,NM_005015,10.5672879852575,5.29334273442728"))
```

I want to confirm the match when reading lines. I tried to find out which files has content starting with `NM` or `GE` by the following code

```
which(lapply(lines, function(x) any(grepl(paste(c("^NM_","^GE"),collapse = "|"), x, ignore.case = TRUE))) == T)
```

which is supposed to give index of all the three, but it return `integer(0)`. I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lyst <- list(c("\"ID\",\"SIGNALINTENSITY\",\"SNR\"", "\"NM_012429\",\"7.19739265676517\",\"0.738130599770152\"", 
"\"NM_003980\",\"12.4036181424743\",\"13.753593768862\"", "\"AY044449\",\"8.74973537284918\",\"1.77200602833912\"", 
"\"NM_005015\",\"11.3735054810744\",\"6.76079815107347\""), c("\"ID\",\"SIGNALINTENSITY\",\"SNR\"", 
"\"NM_012429\",\"7.07699512126353\",\"0.987579612646805\"", "\"NM_003980\",\"11.3172936656653\",\"8.38227473088534\"", 
"\"AY044449\",\"9.2865464417786\",\"2.61149606120517\"", "\"NM_005015\",\"10.1228142794354\",\"3.98707517627092\""
), c("ID,SIGNALINTENSITY,SNR", "1,NM_012429,6.44764696592035,0.84120306786724", 
"2,NM_003980,9.52604513443066,3.02404186191898", "3,AY044449,9.11930818670925,2.24361163736047", 
"4,NM_005015,10.5672879852575,5.29334273442728"))
```

Assuming `lyst` is given string as per your question then you can do:

```
lapply(1:length(lyst), function(x)grepl("^NM|^GE",gsub('"',"", lyst[[x]])))
```

**Logic**:

First replacing the ' " ' with nothing using `gsub` then using the '^' to determining if the start of string is NM or GE using grepl.

However, if someone is interested in matching with optional numbers and commas
one can also use this regex:

```
lapply(1:3, function(x)grepl("^(NM|GE)|^\\d+,(NM|GE)",gsub('"',"", lyst[[x]])))
```

**Output:**

```
    > lapply(1:3, function(x)grepl("^(NM|GE)|^\\d+,(NM|GE)",gsub('"',"", lyst[[x]])))
[[1]]
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you, but your answer is not correct, if you can see there are strings that start with  `NM` in the third list also.

Comment: @AwaitedOne no they start with numbers not NM or GE as per your quesiton, you can see it starts with 1, or 2, or 3, something like that. If you change your string correctly you will get correct result with the same code

Comment: @AwaitedOne , I have edited my solution in a way that it will suit your both needs

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <- lapply(
  lines,
  function(x) read.csv(text = x)
)

# [[1]]
#          ID SIGNALINTENSITY        SNR
# 1 NM_012429        7.197393  0.7381306
# 2 NM_003980       12.403618 13.7535938
# 3  AY044449        8.749735  1.7720060
# 4 NM_005015       11.373505  6.7607982
# 
# [[2]]
#          ID SIGNALINTENSITY       SNR
# 1 NM_012429        7.076995 0.9875796
# 2 NM_003980       11.317294 8.3822747
# 3  AY044449        9.286546 2.6114961
# 4 NM_005015       10.122814 3.9870752
# 
# [[3]]
#          ID SIGNALINTENSITY       SNR
# 1 NM_012429        6.447647 0.8412031
# 2 NM_003980        9.526045 3.0240419
# 3  AY044449        9.119308 2.2436116
# 4 NM_005015       10.567288 5.2933427
```

To filter lines:

```
lapply(
  dat,
  function(df) df[grepl("^NM_|^GE", df$ID, ignore.case = TRUE), ]
)

# [[1]]
#          ID SIGNALINTENSITY        SNR
# 1 NM_012429        7.197393  0.7381306
# 2 NM_003980       12.403618 13.7535938
# 4 NM_005015       11.373505  6.7607982
# 
# [[2]]
#          ID SIGNALINTENSITY       SNR
# 1 NM_012429        7.076995 0.9875796
# 2 NM_003980       11.317294 8.3822747
# 4 NM_005015       10.122814 3.9870752
# 
# [[3]]
#          ID SIGNALINTENSITY       SNR
# 1 NM_012429        6.447647 0.8412031
# 2 NM_003980        9.526045 3.0240419
# 4 NM_005015       10.567288 5.2933427
```

Or if just indices are needed:

```
lapply(
  dat,
  function(df) grepl("^NM_|^GE", df$ID, ignore.case = TRUE)
)

# [[1]]
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or with `grep` instead of `grepl`:

```
lapply(
  dat,
  function(df) grep("^NM_|^GE", df$ID, ignore.case = TRUE)
)

# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 4
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2 4
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 2 4
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am not interested to read the data as `.csv`

Comment: @AwaitedOne then just wrapping `grepl("^NM_|^GE", df$ID, ignore.case = TRUE)` in `any()` should do

Comment: There is nothing like `df$ID` when I use `readLines()`, which is shown as sample above.

Comment: `lines` in my answer is the same as in your question, the output of `readLines()`

Comment: `lapply(
  dat,
  function(df) any(grepl("^NM_|^GE", df$ID, ignore.case = TRUE))
)`

Comment: Dear Aurele, I mean you are storing the `lines`, in `dat` by reading as `read.csv` which I don't want. I directly want to operate on `readLines()` output.

Comment: @AwaitedOne Why do you want to avoid `read.csv` since this is csv? What are you trying to do with those indices?